# python, rpy2 installation test - nosetests rpy2 results in failure

Tags: python, nosetests, rpy2

I have the academic version of EPD 7.1 installed on MacOS 10.6.4. 
I installed Rpy2 by invoking `easy_install rpy2

```
Searching for rpy2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
Reading http://rpy.sourceforge.net
Best match: rpy2 2.2.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.4.tar.gz#md5=0192a3c05d8d97971e2bcf888944aff5
Processing rpy2-2.2.4.tar.gz
Running rpy2-2.2.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/st/stQUFIfOG28bmpY9dCspTk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-TE6kYA/rpy2-2.2.4/egg-dist-tmp-qKzkC5
Configuration for R as a library:
  include_dirs: ('/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include', '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64')
  libraries: ('Rblas', 'Rlapack')
  library_dirs: ('/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/x86_64',)
  extra_link_args: ('-framework R', '-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..')
 # OSX-specific (included in extra_link_args)
  framework_dirs: ('-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..',)
  frameworks: ('-framework R',)
warning: no previously-included files matching '*patch*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*diff*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.hg' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching 'dist'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
rpy2.rinterface.tests.test_EmbeddedR: module references __path__
Adding rpy2 2.2.4dev-20111204 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.2.4dev_20111204-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for rpy2
Finished processing dependencies for rpy2
`
```

Then I ran `nosetests rpy2` to test the installation and I received the following errors:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named testRevents)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.2.4dev_20111204-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/rpy2/interactive/tests/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import testRevents
ImportError: No module named testRevents

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.005s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Any ideas whats going on here? I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Could it be that I need to run `python -m 'rpy2.tests'` instead? When i ran this all tests passed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like to test the installation of RPy2 you need to run:

python -m 'rpy2.tests'